# Return multiple SQL query results to text boxes

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, t-sql, ado.net

I've currently got three tables, Student, Less/Stu, Lessons and Class

Using sql queries I have managed to use a combo box to return a class code to a text box. Now I have created a SELECT query that should return the values from Lessons that are linked with that Class code. As there are six lessons linked to a class I would like these rows to populate multiple text boxes.

Lesson Code  Lesson Name  Lesson Credit... are the three columns within the lessons table. So there should be six rows of results to populate the text boxes. The current Code I have

```
string conString = "DATA SOURCE HERE";
string query = @"SELECT [Lesson ID],[LessonName],[LessonCredits] from Lessons WHERE ClassID ='" + txtClassID.Text + "' ;";
SqlConnection conDateBase = new SqlConnection(conString);
SqlCommand cmdDatabase = new SqlCommand(query, conDateBase);

conDateBase.Open();
SqlDataReader myReader = cmdDatabase.ExecuteReader();

while (myReader.Read())
{
    string sLessID = myReader.GetString(myReader.GetOrdinal("Lesson ID"));
    string sLessNam = myReader.GetString(myReader.GetOrdinal("LessonName"));
    string sLessCred = myReader.GetString(myReader.GetOrdinal("LessonCredits"));

    txtLessId1.Text= sLessID;
    txtLessName1.Text = sLessNam;
    txtLessCred1.Text = sLessCred;
}
```

This code only returns the last value in the lessons table that is related to the class ID, I have a feeling I need to put the results from the query into a loop then store into an array then assign the text boxes to the array?

Comment: Your textboxes could only show a single record (IE the data extracted by a single loop from the datareader) at the following loop you overwrite the previous text. So, unless you are fine with concatenating string then you should choose another kind of control suited for this scenario, (A ListView or a DataGridView)

Comment: use parameters in your sql. Do it right from the beginning : http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/lesson06

Comment: I have used a DataGridView in a test but I will need to select data from that datagrid and combine it with student information.
So when a student registers to a class (by selecting the current combo box) they select the class ID, this in return selects all the lessons and adds the studentID, lesson ID and lesson name to the Less/Stud table.. IS this possible?

Comment: in this case, given one classid you can have multiple rows for your select. so the text boxes you use could be a list boxes or something, populating each column. Instead of your textbox.text = value, it should be listbox.add.

Comment: You do have loop.   You cannot assign an array to a TextBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it shows only the last row of the table. Cauz you're going through a loop and the loop ends at the last row. For your kind of requirement, I'll giv you two options..

**1**. Create two buttons 'Previous Lesson' and 'Next Lesson', and move through rows while clicking this button

[image]

Add two variables in your Form Class, so that they can be accessed on the button_click event

A System.Data.DataTable variable for storing the lesson data and

An int variable for storing index

```
DataTable Lessons;
    int lessonIndex = 0;
    private void combo_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conDateBase = new SqlConnection();
        conDateBase.ConnectionString = connectionString;
        conDateBase.Open();

        string query = "SELECT [Lesson ID],[LessonName],[LessonCredits] from Lessons WHERE ClassID = @CLASS_ID";
        SqlCommand cmdDatabase = new SqlCommand(query, conDateBase);
        cmdDatabase.Parameters.Add("@CLASS_ID", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtClassID.Text;
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdDatabase);
        DataSet dSet = new System.Data.DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(dSet, "Lessons");
        Lessons = dSet.Tables["Lessons"];
        lessonIndex = 0;
        refreshValues();
    }

    private void btnPreviousLesson_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (lessonIndex > 0 && Lessons != null && Lessons.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            lessonIndex--;
            refreshValues();
        }
    }

    private void btnNextLesson_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Lessons != null && Lessons.Rows.Count > 0 && lessonIndex < Lessons.Rows.Count - 1)
        {
            lessonIndex++;
            refreshValues();
        }
    }

    private void refreshValues()
    {
        txtLessID1.Text = Lessons.Rows[lessonIndex]["Lesson ID"].ToString();
        txtLessName1.Text = Lessons.Rows[lessonIndex]["LessonName"].ToString();
        txtLessCred1.Text = Lessons.Rows[lessonIndex]["LessonCredits"].ToString();
    }
```

.

**2**. Show the lesson data on a DataGridView

[image]

Code as same as above on the combo_DropDown event, skip last two lines and other events/functions and add these.

```
  DataSet dSet = new System.Data.DataSet();
  adapter.Fill(dSet, "Lessons");
  Lessons = dSet.Tables["Lessons"];
  dataGridView1.DataSource = Lessons;
```